# Swift dynamic cast failure - AnyObject?! to String

Tags: swift

I've just updated to Xcode 6 beta 6 and I have a following problem with my code which was working before

```
let reminderSubject = reminder["subject"]
println("reminderSubject: \(reminderSubject)")
let tempTuple = (reminderSubject as String)
```

reminderSubject is of type AnyObject?! when I try to downcast it to String it crashes with "Swift dynamic cast failure" message. The value printed by println is: Optional(Hey its Test!)

So the question is how to correctly cast AnyObject?! to String in Swift?

Comment: Typically you'd want to check to see if there actually *was* an item with that key in your dictionary, and therefore use a path like `if let reminderSubject = reminder["subject"] { ... }`, which would execute only if your reminder had a subject, and make `reminderSubject` non-optional. You may want to re-think your approach here; if you start seeing lots of exclamation marks it's a bit of a clue you're not writing particularly Swifty code, in my opinion.

Comment: @MattGibson thanks for your insight - I'll take a look at this since my current solution is "ugly as hell" even for me ;)

Answer (score 1):

Ok I've done it with:

```
let tempTuple = ("\(reminderSubject!!)")
```